# task number is larger than replicas in swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Why the number of running task is larger than I specific with the blow command.

```
docker service create \
 --env  TERM=xterm \
 --network mynet \
 --replicas=1  \
 --name backend mybackend
```

Then I execute  `docker service ls`, shows

```
ID            NAME       REPLICAS  IMAGE                           COMMAND
a08kvffdvryy  mybackend  3/1       docker.local:5000/mybackend
```

I am confused by `3/1`. Does anyone know that?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when this happens, it is because the tasks in your service are failing. The dead container is kept around for a short time before it is deleted, giving you a chance to inspect logs.

Until that dead/stopped task is actually deleted, it counts towards the total number of tasks active for that service, giving a count higher than the replicas requested.

Comment: Yes, It is because the tasks are failiing. I create a task set replicas with 1 , but I found there are two tasks is running  state and four tasks history is faled. So I thought there are not lock in docker swarm mode. For us, we have to insure the task only run one process. So, now, I added a lock on etcd with script.